# Spring JPA Repository save not Inserting into the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm launching a spring-boot application which contains an `@Service` class:

```
@Service
@Transactional (value = MatrixModelConfiguration.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_MATRIX)
public class MatrixTubeService implements IMatrixTubeService {

    @Autowired
    MatrixTubeRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        boolean txn = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();
        System.out.println("flush txn exist " + txn);
        repository.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public MatrixTube save(MatrixTube matrixTube) {
        boolean txn = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();       
        String txnName = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName();
        System.out.println("save txn exist " + txn + " as " + txnName);
        return repository.save(matrixTube);
    }
 .
 .
 .
```

wrapping the calls to this simple `@EnableJpaRepositories` class:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = MatrixModelConfiguration.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_MATRIX, 
                                   transactionManagerRef = MatrixModelConfiguration.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_MATRIX)
            public interface MatrixTubeRepository extends JpaRepository<MatrixTube, Long> {

    }
```

This code is in a dependent jar and run perfect in 2 out of three parent projects. In the case where it doesn't, INSERTs/UPDATEs do not apply to the database. In fact they don't even show in the debug output.

- I've added the a txn manager check in the save and verified the txn
  is active and available.
- I am not seeing any `Exception` while running
- All other `JpaRepository` implementations are working as expected

I added a call to `service.flush()` directly after a `service.save()` of a newly created object and again after a few updates a previously read object (within the same txn) and in both instances, I see the txn is active in the flush method, but when `repository.flush()` is called, I get a "no transaction is in progress" exception.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is implementation for MatrixTubeRepository?

Comment: @gopal it is spring data jpa, does not need imlementation

Comment: Correct, I'm currently relying on Free CRUD methods.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe spring-test set rollback default value is true,

adding   `@Rollback(false)`  soveld my problem.

Answer (score 1):

With springdatajpa you do not need all this magic. txn etc.

Use this annotation in you main application class.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = MatrixModelConfiguration.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_MATRIX, 
                                   transactionManagerRef = MatrixModelConfiguration.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_MATRIX)
```

Start with this tutorial. Spring data jpa is a little magical comparing to standard Hibernate/jpa.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: I don't understand this comment? I'm using the above mentioned *Refs because my example is implemented in conjunction with several JpaRepository implementations, each with different performance considerations etc. and they all need to coexist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with spawning a new thread from within the transaction, which actually performed the SQL inserts well after (in computer time) the transaction had been committed.

Not sure why there were no exceptions thrown, but getting the inserts back into the transactional thread fixed everything.

Comment: Can you provide more info, how had you done this?